# TikZ: Drawing boundary region around arbitrary line

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

In Figure 9 of Chapter 4 of Stein and Shakarchi's real analysis lecture notes (p. 137, [see here](http://www.cmat.edu.uy/%7Emordecki/courses/medida2013/book.pdf)), the authors trace out a region up to some value of lowercase delta. This seems like a simple TikZ problem but I'm having difficulty coding it (very much a TikZ beginner). Would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to get started. Thanks!

[image: Fig. 9: The arbitrary curve gamma and the boundary set.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly a perfect solution, but if you want something simple you could just use Bézier curves to draw Gamma and two dotted lines above and below, and then just complete the boundary of the region with arcs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0,0) .. controls (2,1) and (4,-1) .. (6,0) node[yshift=-2mm] {\(\Gamma\)};
    \draw[dotted, thick] (-.2, .5) .. controls (1.8,1.5) and (3.8, -.5) .. (5.8, .5);
    \draw[dotted, thick] ( .2,-.5) .. controls (2.2, .5) and (4.2,-1.5) .. (6.2,-.5);
    \draw[dotted, thick] (-.2, .5) arc[start angle=115, end angle=290, radius=.54];
    \draw[dotted, thick] (6.2,-.5) arc[start angle=-70, end angle=115, radius=.54];
    \node at (1,1) {\(\Gamma^\delta\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for comparison, here is a version in [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html), the drawing language built in to LuaLaTex.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef sausage expr d of p = 
  for t=0 step 1/4 until length p:
    point t of p shifted (d * unitvector(direction t of p rotated 90))
    {direction t of p} ..
  endfor 
  for t=length p step -1/4 until 0:
    point t of p shifted (d * unitvector(direction t of p rotated -90)) 
    {- direction t of p} ..
  endfor cycle
enddef;

beginfig(1);
path p, s;

p = origin {dir 42} .. 200 right {dir 42};
s = sausage 16 of p;

draw p;
draw s dashed withdots scaled 1/2;

label.lrt("$\Gamma$", point 7/8 of p);
label.top("$\Gamma^\delta$", directionpoint right of s);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

My `sausage d of p` macro calculates the surrounding path automatically.  It should work with any smooth, non-closed path `p`, for any reasonably small displacement `d`.